# Access Simple xml object attributes

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I am having a very strange issue i have a xml file structure like this:

```
<hooks>
    <hook module="socialsharing" hook="displayHeader" position="1"/>
    <hook module="socialsharing" hook="displayRightColumnProduct" position="1"/>
    <hook module="socialsharing" hook="actionObjectProductUpdateAfter" position="1"/>
    <hook module="socialsharing" hook="actionObjectProductDeleteAfter" position="1"/>
    <hook module="socialsharing" hook="displayCompareExtraInformation" position="1"/>
    <hook module="blockbanner" hook="displayHeader" position="2"/>
    <hook module="blockbanner" hook="displayBanner" position="1"/>
    <hook module="blockbanner" hook="actionObjectLanguageAddAfter" position="1"/>
    <hook module="blockbestsellers" hook="displayLeftColumn" position="1" exceptions="category"/>
    <hook module="blockbestsellers" hook="displayHeader" position="3"/>
    <hook module="blockbestsellers" hook="actionProductAdd" position="1"/>
    <hook module="blockbestsellers" hook="actionProductUpdate" position="1"/>
</hooks>
```

And This is the code snippet i am working with:

```
if($xmlHooks=simplexml_load_file(_PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/assests/hooks.xml'))
        {


            foreach ($xmlHooks as $xmlHook)
            {
                die(print_r($xmlHook->attributes()->module));

            }   

        }
```

But it always outputs this no matter how i access it:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => socialsharing
)
```

Just want to get socialsharing freely not in array or object so i can use this word further.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats what `print_r()` will show, you can use:

```
echo $xmlHook->attributes()->module
```

or if you want it to be assigned, cast a string `(string)` on it:

```
$var = (string) $xmlHook->attributes()->module;
```